# Why can ArrayLists store different object while arrays cannot?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Putting different types of Objects into an [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) will throw an [`ArrayStoreException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html), while putting different types of objects into an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) works.

As far as I know, the ArrayList is built on top of an array, so why does it work there? Is it implemented differently?

I searched but found no answer.

Comment: Are you comparing apples to apples? I.e. `Object[]` to `ArrayList<Object>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ArrayList` has a field called [`Object[] elementData`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.0elementData) which means an `ArrayList` supports adding every kind of object reference. This also means that `ArrayList` doesn't support primitive types such as `int` or `char`, but instead their wrapper classes `Integer` and `Character`, respectively.

Arrays are usually for single-type elements since their declaration, unless you declare them as `Object[]`. For primitive types, there's no generic array, just the arrays of primitives `int[]`, `char[]` and on...

---

> if you create an Object[] array, and put in strings and afterwards a date object, it will throw an exception

Here's a code that proves the contrary, compiles and executes with no problem by having an `Object[]` storing `String`s and a `Date`:

```
Object[] objects = { "hello", "world", new Date() };
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(objects));
```

Output (the Date will depend on the current time of your pc):

```
[hello, world, Tue Aug 12 00:09:00 GMT 2014]
```

You can check it working [here](http://ideone.com/TG3BGu).

Comment: Just a question, aren't ArrayLists templated? Doesn't that mean that it has a T[] elementData instead, unless you define T as Object? Or is the template optional and it defaults to Object[]?

Comment: @StealthyHunter7 that's for compilation purpose, so you can't insert an `Integer` into a `List<String>`. But at runtime, they get [type erasured](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) and become raw types.

Comment: I mean, if you create an Object[] array, and put in strings and afterwards a date object, it will throw an exception, but this doesnt happen with ArrayList<Object> or an ArrayList without generics(It will simply replace T with Object)

Comment: @DeroLeaq I updated the answer with a code that proves the contrary. If you happen to encounter such problem, please provide a piece of code that demonstrates this error to analyze it and provide a solution for it.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaing, after seing your example I got my code working!

Answer (score 2):

An `ArrayStoreException` can only arise when you've cast an array `SomeClass[]` to an array `TheSuperClass[]`.  It doesn't get thrown in other situations.  For example:

```
A[] array = new A[100];
```

The elements of `array` can be objects of class `A` or any subclass of `A`, and you'll never get `ArrayStoreException`.  Similarly:

```
Object[] array = new Object[100];
```

The elements of this array can be anything.  No matter what you assign `array[n]` to, this won't throw an `ArrayStoreException`.

The issue comes when you use `new` to create an array of one type, and then cast it (perhaps implicitly) to an array of some superclass type:

```
A[] array = new B[100];   // legal if B is a subclass of A
C[] array2 = new C[100];  
Object[] array3;
array3 = array2;          // legal even though `array2` is C[]
```

This kind of cast is legal.  **BUT** if you then try to assign something that doesn't fit into the type used to create the array, you'll get `ArrayStoreException`.

```
array[1] = new A();
```

The only things that can be assigned into `array[n]` are `B` or subclasses of `B`.  The compiler can't catch the above error at compile time, but it throws an exception at runtime.

```
array3[1] = "some string";
```

Even though `array3` is an `Object[]` array, you can't assign any old object to its elements; they have to be `C` or subclasses of `C`.

The reason this isn't a problem with `ArrayList` is that you just can't do the same kind of cast.

```
ArrayList<A> array = new ArrayList<B>();   // illegal even if B is a subclass of A
ArrayList<C> array2 = new ArrayList<C>();
ArrayList<Object> array3;
array3 = array2;  // illegal
```

So it's not really a matter of arrays being more restricted than `ArrayList`.  Arrays have an exception in a situation that just can't come up with `ArrayList`s.

**EDIT** (based on Luiggi's comment): OK, it looks like you can force the wrong kind of object into an `ArrayList` with some trickery:

```
((ArrayList)array2).add(x);
```

where `x` can have any type; it doesn't have to be of type `C`.  But **never, never, never** do this.  Especially in any program I might have to maintain one day.

Comment: Note that you can still add `Object` elements in `array2` and make it w/o a compiler exception nor a runtime exception, no reflection involved.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! Indeed my problen was an api method casting the array without me knowing it so I didn't recognize it(like you would with generics)